# Why can't I use constant number instead of this.item.number?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

```html
<template>
    <Page>
        <ActionBar title="item" />
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label textWrap="true" v-for="n in times" :text="n" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ["item"],
        data() {
            return {
                times: this.item.subTotal - this.item.subtrackfromTotal // OK
                // times: 9 - 5, // OK
                // times: this.item.subTotal - 5 //error: INVALID ARRAY LENGTH
            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

---

I want to subtract **5** from (number field of my data) and => use it in `v-for="n in times"`
 but when I use a constant number *such as 5*, it gives an INVALID ARRAY LENGTH error.

Why does `times: this.item.subTotal - 5` fails?

Please help me to figure out; how to use operators over my data and constant numbers, and at the same time make vue believe that I am sending a constant number not an array?

When  I tried `times: this.item.subTotal - this.item.subtrackfromTotal`  or `times: 9 - 5`Vue accepts times as a constant number. 
         But When I try `times: this.item.subTotal - 5` It gives INVALID ARRAY LENGTH error.

Thanks for your replies in advance.

---

### Please Check Code in {N} Playground

#### [Playground of "modify counts (item.number - 5)"](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=dXRhda&v=4)

Comment: ```times: (this.item.subTotal >= 0)? this.item.subTotal - 5 :  this.item.subTotal ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because the value is negative.

For one of your items the value of `this.item.subTotal` is 4, so `times` is -1.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      times: -1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="a in times"></div>
</div>
```

How exactly you fix it depends on what you want the behaviour to be in that case. Maybe this?

```js
times: Math.max(0, this.item.subTotal - 5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a kind of answer which was hard to find by searching in the documentation.